# Struggling to debug my leetcode solution for LRU Cache

Tags: python

I am working on the LeetCode problem [LRU Cache](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/) and I want to understand why my code does not work.

My idea was to keep a queue of valid keys and a dictionary of tuples `(isValid, value)`. Everytime `get` is called I wanted to make the next key on the queue invalid and update the dictionary tuple for that key to be `(False, value)`.

I know that there are better solutions out there I just really want to know why mine doesn't work, so I can become a better debugger/programmer in general. Thank you so much in advance for any and all help!

This is my code so far:

```
class LRUCache:

    def __init__(self, capacity: int):
        self.d = dict()
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.validKeys = Queue()

    def get(self, key: int) -> int:
        (isValid, value) = self.d.get(key, (False, -1))
        if isValid:
            return value
        else:
            return -1

    def put(self, key: int, value: int) -> None:
        if self.validKeys.getSize() >= self.capacity:
            lastUsedKey = self.validKeys.dequeue()
            (_, val) = self.d[lastUsedKey]
            self.d[lastUsedKey] = (False, val)
        # only enqueue a new key if it doesn't exist in the cache already, was part of the problem statement
        if self.d.get(key, None) is None:
            self.d[key] = (True, value)
            self.validKeys.enqueue(key)
```

This is the expected output:
`[null,null,null,1,null,-1,null,-1,3,4]`

This is my output:
`[null,null,null,1,null,2,null,-1,3,4]`

Note: I'm pretty sure my queue implementation is correct I've posted it below with the test cases I tested it with:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None
        self.val = val

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = self.head
        self.size = 0

    def enqueue(self, val):
        if self.size == 0:
            self.head = Node(val)
            self.tail = self.head
        else:
            self.tail.next = Node(val)
            self.tail = self.tail.next
        self.size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            raise "Queue empty"
        else:
            val = self.head.val
            self.head = self.head.next
            self.size -= 1
            return val

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    def __repr__(self):
        curr = self.head
        res = ''
        while curr is not None:
            res += str(curr.val)
            curr = curr.next
        return res

obj = Queue()
assert obj.getSize() == 0
obj.enqueue(1)
assert obj.getSize() == 1
assert obj.dequeue() == 1
assert obj.getSize() == 0
obj.enqueue(1)
obj.enqueue(2)
obj.enqueue(3)
assert obj.getSize() == 3
assert obj.dequeue() == 1
assert obj.dequeue() == 2
assert obj.dequeue() == 3
assert obj.getSize() == 0
```

Comment: Can you add the code that produces your output? It's really helpful when a potential answer-er can copy/paste your code right into the console and see what you see.

Comment: Yeah sorry this is a bit inconvenient Leetcode has a text box where you can make a test case really simply, it's the default test case: ```["LRUCache","put","put","get","put","get","put","get","get","get"]
[[2],[1,1],[2,2],[1],[3,3],[2],[4,4],[1],[3],[4]] ```